# ¿Cómo unir multiples archivos shapefile en un único archivo shapefile en R?

Tags: r, lista

Necesito unir varios archivos shapefile de la clase SpatialPolygonsDataFrame en uno solo y guardarlo. Para leer mis archivos en R uso:

```
files <- list.files(path = "", pattern = "*.shp", recursive = T), a partir de esto construyo un bucle para leer los archivos:

for (x in files){
  # files
  pol<- readShapePoly(paste(sep="","",x),proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

 }
```

pero, ¿Qué debo introducir en el bucle anterior para unir los shapefiles, que contienen poligonos, en un sólo shapefile y guardarlo?

Gracias

---

Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Hasta el momento he conseguido leer mis archivos shapefile en una lista de R. Esa lista está formada por objetos espaciales de la clase SpatialPolygonsDataFrame tal y como muestro a continuación:

```
files <- list.files(path = "F:/", pattern = "*.shp", recursive = T)
files_total<-list()
for (i in files) {
  files_total[[i]]<- readShapePoly(paste(sep="","F://",i),proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
  }
Me devuelve lo siguiente:

$`ker100_sp1.shp`
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 35.26667, 83.41545, -16.2, 18.17254  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 2
names       : SP_ID, dummy 
min values  :     1,     0 
max values  :     1,     0 

$`ker100_sp2.shp`
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 95.18967, 116.701, -6.911263, 27.11667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 2
names       : SP_ID, dummy 
min values  :     1,     0 
max values  :     1,     0
```

El problema es que sigo sin saber como unir la lista de tamaño 130 a una única y guardarla como un shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que ya tenés la lista con un objeto de la clase SpatialPolygonDataFrame en cada [[]]  leido con readOGR
Pasas esa lista como argumento a la función unir_SPDF(). Podría usar el loop sólo, pero prefiero hacerlo dentro de una función. El output de esa función es la unión (con raster::union) de cada elemento de la lista en un solo SpatialPolygonDataFrame

```
library(raster)                                                                    #Para union() Hay una más primitiva de `sp::`, también `rgdal`. Esta funcionó primero. 
unir_SPDF <- function(lista_de_shp) {
  stopifnot(!any(sapply(lista_de_shp, class)=="SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"))         #Detiene si algún elemento de la lista no es de la clase correcta
  shp <- lista_de_shp[[1]]                                                         #Primer elemento, sobre este se agregan incrementalmente los restantes. Podría ser lento!
    for (i in 2:length(lista_de_shp)) {     
      shp <- union(shp, lista_de_shp[[i]])   
      }
  return(shp)                               
  }
```

Para escribir el archivo shp y compañía.

```
# Guarda los archivos en getwd()/tempdir. Se puede cambiar, pero siembre será relativo a getwd()
# layer="strig" será el nombre de los archivos. 

foo <- unir_SPDF(lista_de_shp) 
writeOGR(obj=foo, dsn="tempdir", layer="bar", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Prueba de lectura.

```
readOGR("./tempdir", "bar")
```